# Privacy level for user objects in user content site

Tags: database-design, social-networking

Is it better to store all object metadata like privacy level in the content table itself or have a separate master meta table? Objects are like Links, Photos, Video, Tags, Comments, etc. Currently i have 14 different object types, each with its own user table. I see advantages and disadvantages both ways:

If in 1 table then i can query all privacy level across objects with a single query otherwise there are multiple tables to query. If in different tables then table maintenance will be easier as it wont grow that big like if photo table has say 10 millions rows, video has 20 million, links has 40 million then that means metadata table will have 70 million rows.

I am implementing something similar to the object privacy levels we see on most social sites today but not sure on the best way to design it. And also if the privacy levels should be lookup values or enums or in application logic totally?

** The trickest part is the profile details privacy level. There are over 50 fields each with its own privacy level. So if i store 50 different privacy levels in 1 table i dont know if it will work well?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of your problem, I guess you can do the following:

Have 1 table which has all privileges, like access some resource or view some profile, then all other "objects" (as you call them) can have a foreign key to each privilege they have.

So, the multiplicity will be N to N, and you will have to add indexes to speed up your queries.

Particulary, I recomend to use NOSQL solutions to improve performance in querys and databases becauses readings could be way too fast.

Hope this clarify your mind & helps you a litle.
Cheers,